# Show number of new records on page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, records

I want to display the exact number of new entries (records) on my page of my phpmyadmin database after reloading the page. I looked online but couldn't find anything usefull. Maybe someone can help me. This is the code for the page:

```
<?php
header("Refresh: 120");
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="verzoekstyle.css">
<title>Verzoekpagina DJ</title>
</head>
<body id="body">
<div id="tabel">
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('database','username','password');

    if (!$con)
    {
        echo 'Geen verbinding met server';
    }

    if (!mysqli_select_db($con, 'eventqy179_verzoeken'))
    {
        echo 'Database niet geselecteerd';
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM info";
    $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    if(!$query)
    {
        echo 'Onbekende fout gevonden';
    }

    echo '
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
    <th><h3><b>Artiest</b></h3></th>
    <th><h3><b>Titel</b></h3></th>
    <th><h3><b>Verwijderen</b></h3></th>
    </tr>';

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><h3>'.$row['artiest'].'</h3></td>';
        echo '<td><h3>'.$row['titel'].'</h3></td>';
        echo '<td><h3><a href=delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'>Verwijderen</a></h3></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';

?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you define "new records"? Is it the number of records added since the last time it was displayed? Is it the number of records added today or since a specific date/time?

Comment: `$row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($query);` after `mysqli_query()` give you the number of results.

Comment: Define "new entries". What number are you trying to display?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what phpmyadmin is

Comment: It is the number of records added since the last time the page refreshed (every 120 seconds).

Comment: Already found another way, just "ORDER BY id DESC". Question is therefor answered.

Answer (score 0):

Already found another way, just `ORDER BY id DESC`. Question is therefor answered